# In google docs, when you pass a bunch of cells into a custom function, how do you determine the length?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

On the spreadsheet :

```
    A            B
1   monkey       =countAnimals(A1:A4)
2   cat
3   llama
4   mouse
```

On the custom script page :

```
function countAnimals(data) {
    data.length; 
}
```

Then when I hit play to test my function, I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. (line 32, file "")
```

So, how do I get the length of data?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need apps script. The formula on any cell will do this.
    =COUNTA(A1:A4)

If you really want to use a user defined function, the following will work. Note the quotes around the range "A1:A4".

```
=countAnimals("A1:A4")

function countAnimals(data) {
ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var num=ss.getRange(data).getValues().length
return num
}
```

Comment: I suppose that would work, may even work in my actual non-simplified version of this problem... just seems there should be a way to access the properties of the thing passed to countAnimals()